# Как вытащить 3D модель из игры?

Tags: 3d

В общем пытался вытащить из игры 3Д модель программами **3DRipperDX** и  **NinjaRipper**.
Увы не вышло единственное что вышло так это "вытащить" текстуру модели с помощью **NinjaRipper**.

После этого решил попробовать **фотограмметрией** "вытащить" модель (хотя бы с приблизительными характеристиками).

Увы также не вышло, я как понял программы для фотограмметрии не могут "зацепиться" за объект, почему так ??

Как это исправить ???

Есть ли программы которые могли бы "снять" модель из запущенной программы ???

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]